# Mailchimp error recipient has too many recent signup requests

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using `Mailchimp api` to subscribe user but I am getting error

```
Recipient "anonymized@gmail.com" has too many recent signup requests
```

I am trying to add user in list direct from mailchimp account I am getting same error or even same error when I am trying to add user via PHP script.

I also try it with different browser and with new system even with different internet but i am getting same error kindly please help me how can i solve it?

Comment: Was the user subscribed multiple times before?, i.e. subscribed and then deleted, and then again subscribed, and so on. I found out this related article, maybe it can help you with the issue: https://brianhogg.com/avoid-mailchimp-too-many-attempts-signup-error/

Comment: Note that this error can happen with the MailChimp-provided forms as well. I was testing resubscribing a formerly subscribed email address with the PHP API (probably tried over a dozen times), always getting errorCode `212` (which occurs when you try to resubscribe someone already subscribed)—and then tried to sign up via an official MailChimp form, and got the `too many recent signup requests` error, preventing the form from being submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason why this happens, which i just experienced:
user subscriptions through an form without csrf protection got spammed by external services with emails from different regions. While the reasons for doing so are unclear to me, MailChimp seems to have a protection against that, thus error.

The underlying form should get a csrf-protection tho, to protect the users MC does not know about yet.

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to your API limitation, you surpassed the user subscription limits.
most of the time it will pass by 24 hours but if this is very urgent then ask Mailchimp support for limitation lift, but I think they will ask for quarantine to not happen again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was due to missing & in the form submit url before the parameters.